# How can I write a notification email workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

I was trying to write a sharepoint designer WF for sharepoint online. I couldn't able to write the workflow that sends an email reminder for people who didn't sign out from their sign in/out sheet(which is a sharepoint list with InfoPath form)

- This form has sign in and sign Out field
- the logic is... If a person is not sign out send a reminder email with the 
  link to the form on each day like at 9 pm or 10 hours after Sign In.

I want the work flow to Initiate, If the sign out field is Empty to send the reminder every day at 8 Pm (this is the time every body leave the office) . The other easier triger will be Send a reminder workflow 10 hours after sign in.

Any help will be Much appreciated.

Comment: What is the logic in the workflow that initiates the email (e.g. If Status = Open then Email.....)?

Comment: David, Thanks for your interest to help. The work flow will be initiated automatically When the sign out field is empty and send the reminder at 8 PM every day. The other easier way is work flow will have initiated and send the email 10 hours after sign in, so everybody will receive their

Answer (score 1):

You could try to create a loop in your workflow that will run every 24 hours. When it runs it will check if the user is signed out or not and will either send an email or pause until the next day.